# Gradle multi module project cannot find module dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build simple java project in Intellij that has many modules.

I've got following project structure:
[project_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4W0Z.png)

my root project `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.wat'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

my root project `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'Foot'
include 'app'
include 'model'
```

and my app module `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.wat'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile project ':model'
}
```

When I'm refreshing the project I get following error:

```
Error:(14, 0) Could not get unknown property ':model' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\lukas\IdeaProjects\Foot\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

I was looking for similar problems but none of their solutions was resolving mine.

When I was leaving only

```
dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile project ':model'
}
```

In each module `build.gradle`

I get the following error:

```
Error:(2, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'testCompile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Foot' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.0 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'Foot' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
compile project(path: ':model', configuration: 'compile')
```

instead of

```
compile project ':model'
```

Comment: This works. Had the same issues. Thank you. Though not on sub dependencies of subdependencies

Comment: implementation project(path: ':model', configuration: 'default') worked for me